# ffplay file.wav 18 audio channels

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, wav, multi-channel

On Linux I have an 18 channel wav file that I can play with aplay or play(sox) without problems. The 18 channels are played well.
If I want to play it with ffplay I get this:

```
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, wav, from 'projetks2.wav':KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Metadata:
    encoded_by      : REAPER
    date            : 2024-01-25
    creation_time   : 18-06-59
    time_reference  : 24000
  Duration: 00:00:03.20, bitrate: 20737 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 18 channels, s32 (24 bit), 20736 kb/s
Invalid sample rate or channel count!
Failed to open file 'projetks2.wav' or configure filtergraph
```

why ? and how to fix this?

Comment: Playing 18 audio channels is not supported by FFplay. The issue is related to the supported standard channel layouts. For getting a list of standard layouts, execute: `ffplay -layouts`. There is probably a way to mix down the channels to say 16 channels before playing. What is the actual "hardware" layout of your system?